# How to test an Internet connection with firewall on?

Tags: firewall, internet-connection

I have `Windows 10` pro with its native `Bitdefender` firewall on. All online tools for testing the Internet connection fail when testing packet loss due to the firewall. I could turn it off during the test but that's not exactly recommended. Any suggestion for making such tests without turning the firewall off?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to actually test. Use an online open port checker if you want to test for various ports (like the ones used by game servers).

Comment: I want to test my connection for packet loss.

Comment: Open the required ports in the firewall.

Comment: Use fastping to ping any outer site for a few minutes. Outgoing ICMP should be working even with the Firewall on. You can also output the result in a text file (or make a log-like file if you want to test this on a long term).